# store shell command output to ruby variable or chef

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, cookbook

Hi I want to store output of a shell command into chef variable. I have seen some way but not able to get how to do it.

Here is what I have tried so far

```
    current_version = `#{node['kayako_nginx']['prefix']}/sbin/nginx -v | grep -Po "(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)"`
  print "cheking version of nginx  #{current_version}"
```

it is executing command but not storing it

this is the output while executing chef

```
 nginx version: nginx/1.5.3
cheking version of nginx
```

Comment: What do you mean "store"? Are you trying to get the version of nginx? That should be exposed via the nginx ohai plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Most probably you have a problem in your first string. Try it like this

```
current_version = `#{node['kayako_nginx']['prefix']}/sbin/nginx -v | grep -Eo "(\d+\.\d+\.\d+)"`
```

grep options have changed to `-Eo`

Version without parentheses should work too

```
current_version = `#{node['kayako_nginx']['prefix']}/sbin/nginx -v | grep -Eo "\d+\.\d+\.\d+"`
```